# Disabling policies while running tests sailsjs

Tags: sails.js, mocha.js

Is there any way to disable policies while running `npm test` in sails.js application ?

My `config/policies.js` looks like this,

`module.exports.policies = {
      '*': 'isLoggedIn',
    };`

all of my test cases are failing with following error

`Uncaught Error: expected 200 "OK", got 401 "Unauthorized"`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a environment variable to control this. For example:

```
module.exports.policies = {
  '*': process.env.IS_TEST ? true : 'isLoggedIn',
};
```

And then, you run this on your terminal:

`IS_TEST=1 npm test`